# Access the "request" variable on Rails controller tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

I have the following code

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should display the page in german" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    # ...
    request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = :index
    # ...
  end
end
```

If I run this rails functional test with

```
$ rake test:functionals
```

I get this error:

```
test_should_display_the_page_in_german(ApplicationControllerTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for #<ApplicationControllerTest:0x1044c6d00>
```

How can i Access the "request" variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] = :index
```

[Testing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

4.4 Instance Variables Available
You also have access to three instance variables in your functional tests:

```
@controller – The controller processing the request
@request – The request
@response – The response
```